# Eloquent Select View

Tags: eloquent

I'm trying to make a select in a view

```
ERRO: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1615 Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared (SQL: SELECT vw_pontos.usuario_id, vw_pontos.nome, SUM(vw_pontos.pontos) AS pontos FROM vw_pontos GROUP BY vw_pontos.usuario_id ORDER BY pontos DESC, nome ASC)

$results = DB::table('vw_pontos')
        ->select([
            'vw_pontos.usuario_id',
            'vw_pontos.nome',
            DB::raw('SUM(vw_pontos.pontos) AS pontos')
        ])
        ->groupBy('usuario_id')
        ->orderBy('pontos', 'desc')
        ->orderBy('nome', 'asc')
        ->get();
```

What is the correct way to call a view?

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of semantics, your question is not specific to Eloquent. Rather, the example you provide utilizes Query Builder. You may wish to adjust the tag on the question accordingly.

As to the problem, I don't believe there to be anything wrong with your code.

A quick-fix may be to employ `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` (and this may be your only option, if you cannot modify the MySQL configuration).

Edit your `.env` file and add to the MySQL configuration:

```
'options'   => [
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true
]
```

A more complete example:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
    'options'   => [
        \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true
    ]
],
```

This approach is described in more detail at https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/general-error-1615-prepared-statement-needs-to-be-re-prepared-selecting-mysql-view/replies/119726 (among other places).